# SRAM based cache flush operation

Tags: caching, memory, riscv

I doubt in how designed cache flush operation for SRAM based cache. You know more commonly cache structure have multi-way and they use some company's SRAM design. My question is that as you know when power up all information(bits) in cache are unknown so how cache flush operation can be performed for power-up and fencei like instruction flush? Additionally is it enough to flush valid bits of every line(so we can put valid bits in registers and flush end in one cycle) to flush cache or at least one flush operation is neccessary for tag_array, valid_array, node_array etc. to give them known value?
Thanks.